# How to draw compactification and completely regular diagrams in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, asymptote

How can we draw diagrams like this:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Slowly and carefully.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site,
a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I
get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application
(e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this
complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too 
localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a
[minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228):
you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: For what it's worth: you could check out [examples for TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/). Then please do prepare an MWE. :)

Comment: something that might get you started: [How to draw function domain/co-domain (range) diagram?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72719)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

This kind of diagrams can be easily created in `Asymptote` in several simple steps:

prepare arrays of points, that define curves and contours,
for example:

```
// Left contour points
pair[] pa={
(134,37),
(193,47),
(196,82),
(150,111),
(90,117),
(33,98),
(9,73),
(7,57),
(29,48),
(80,49),
};
```

build the actual curves (paths) from prepared points and draw them
    (`..cycle` is added in case of closed contour):

```
guide ga=graph(pa,operator..)..cycle;    
draw(ga,linePen);
```

prepare arrays of `TeX` labels and their coordinates and draw them in a `for`-loop:

```
pair[] labelPos={
(71,76),
(232,103),
(406,71),
(446,110),
};

string[] labelTeX={
"$(X,T)$",
"$f:X\rightarrow Z$",
"$Z$",
"$(Y,T^\prime)$",
};

for(int i=0;i<labelTeX.length;++i){
  label(labelTeX[i],labelPos[i]);
}
```

The second diagram needs a `filldraw` command to draw a filled region.

A complete source `diag.tex` is here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
size(400);
import graph;

// Left contour points
pair[] pa={
(134,37),
(193,47),
(196,82),
(150,111),
(90,117),
(33,98),
(9,73),
(7,57),
(29,48),
(80,49),
};

// Right outer contour points
pair[] pb={
(453,25),
(469,41),
(483,58),
(494,84),
(485,112),
(462,132),
(441,138),
(422,146),
(411,149),
(389,147),
(357,140),
(280,100),
(268,86),
(261,74),
(267,65),
(277,57),
(291,38),
(307,17),
(337,8),
(401,7),
};

// Right inner contour points
pair[] pc={
(414,48),
(426,67),
(425,100),
(401,110),
(376,111),
(343,104),
(330,102),
(314,89),
(306,81),
(309,71),
(316,63),
(332,57),
(356,46),
(386,40),
};


// Arrow points
pair[] parrow={
(122,79),
(234,93),
(372,73),
};

pair[] labelPos={
(71,76),
(232,103),
(406,71),
(446,110),
};

string[] labelTeX={
"$(X,T)$",
"$f:X\rightarrow Z$",
"$Z$",
"$(Y,T^\prime)$",
};

defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
pen linePen=darkblue+1.2bp;

for(int i=0;i<labelTeX.length;++i){
label(labelTeX[i],labelPos[i]);
}

guide ga=graph(pa,operator..)..cycle;
guide gb=graph(pb,operator..)..cycle;
guide gc=graph(pc,operator..)..cycle;
guide garrow=graph(parrow,operator..);

draw(ga,linePen);
draw(gb,linePen);
draw(gc,linePen);

draw(garrow,linePen,Arrows(HookHead,size=3));
\end{asy}
\\[20pt]
\begin{asy}
size(400);
import graph;

// Outer contour points
pair[] pb={
(283,46),
(296,60),
(301,94),
(295,134),
(284,171),
(258,198),
(233,205),
(206,215),
(189,220),
(164,217),
(116,201),
(76,176),
(35,144),
(14,120),
(6,107),
(4,85),
(6,68),
(14,47),
(38,49),
(70,47),
(102,41),
(134,35),
(170,29),
(203,24),
(237,26),
(263,35),
};

// Inner contour points
pair[] pc={
(163,107),
(181,111),
(199,121),
(209,134),
(212,151),
(201,172),
(181,179),
(159,180),
(126,172),
(97,162),
(78,145),
(65,133),
(65,124),
(74,119),
(82,120),
(99,120),
(119,117),
(142,115),
};

// span points

pair[] pspan={
(476,120),
(604,120),
};


// Arrow points
pair[] parrow1={
(197,77),
(324,149),
pspan[0]
};

pair[] parrow2={
(189,153),
(218,169),
(266,192),
(327,202),
(395,202),
(433,198),
(466,192),
(508,182),
(541,168),
(568,151),
pspan[0]*(1-0.95)+pspan[1]*0.95
};

pair[] labelPos={
(65,77),
(192,62),
(374,115),
(375,220),
(143,143),
};

string[] labelTeX={
"$(X,T)$",
"$a$",
"$f(a)=0$",
"$f(F)=\{1\}$",
"$F$",
};

defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));

for(int i=0;i<labelTeX.length;++i){
  label(labelTeX[i],labelPos[i]);
}

guide gb=graph(pb,operator..)..cycle;
guide gc=graph(pc,operator..)..cycle;
guide garrow1=graph(parrow1,operator..);
guide garrow2=graph(parrow2,operator..);

pen fillPen=orange;
pen linePen=darkblue+1.2bp;

draw(gb,linePen);
filldraw(gc,fillPen,linePen);

real tickW=3bp;
draw(pspan[0]--pspan[1],linePen);

draw((pspan[0]-(0,tickW))--(pspan[0]+(0,tickW)),linePen);
draw((pspan[1]-(0,tickW))--(pspan[1]+(0,tickW)),linePen);

label("$0$",pspan[0]-(0,tickW),S);
label("$1$",pspan[1]-(0,tickW),S);

draw(garrow1,linePen,Arrow(HookHead,size=3));
filldraw(circle(parrow1[0],3bp),linePen);

draw(garrow2,linePen,Arrow(HookHead,size=3));

\end{asy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

To process it with `latexmk`, create file `latexmkrc`:

```
sub asy {return system("asy '$_[0]'");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

and run `latexmk -pdf diag.tex`.